# Passing $_GET[] parameters to a script with Jumi?

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla

I am using Jumi to include a number of PHP scripts on Joomla! articles and it works great.  The problem I am having is with passing variables (in the form of $_GET parameters) to a PHP script.

Lets say I have a script "index.php" and I wish to pass the $_GET[] parameter "var" with the value of "10".  This would normally be accomplished by pointing to: index.php?var=10.  How do "emulate" this functionality with Jumi?  I was hoping it would be as simple as:

```
{jumi [directory/index.php] [var=10]}
```

The above syntax however is not correct.

Any input would be appreciated.

-- Nicholas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trial and error and guidance from the official Joomla! forums I did solve my problem. Rather than passing a true $_GET[] parameter you can pass a $jumi array and reference that.

I wanted to avoid having to rewrite much of my script so what I did was the following.

1) Make the Jumi call like this:

```
{jumi [directory/index.php] [value]}
```

2) In index.php:

```
if(isset($jumi[0]))
{
    $_GET['PARAM_YOU_WANT_SET'] = $jumi[0];
}
```

This is a very simple example of a quick and easy way to emulate passing a $_GET[] parameter to a script using Jumi.  This approach saved me a great deal of time because I didn't have to rewrite my controller.

-- Nicholas

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread I know but there is something that some people might want to know.

If you are wanting to use Jumi with extra parameters in a Module then Nicholas' tip won't work but there is a way to do it.

There is a "Code written" section of the module and a "Source of code" section.

Put the url/path to the file in the "Source of code" section and then define your variables in the "Code written" section...it will pass the variable to the source file before executing so it will do what is desired.

[image]